# request proxy user and pass

Tags: node.js, proxy, request

How can I config the proxy to use a username and password? The format would be 
IP:Port:User:Pass but the default for request is IP:Port

```
let settings = {
  url,
  headers: {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
  },
  method: 'POST',
  proxy: `http://${ip}:${port}`,
  strictSSL: false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy setup by default follows the syntax:

```
http://username:password@host:port
```

This shall work directly. However if you pass it as a string, you can store it in a variable as:

```
var proxy = "http://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + port;
```

Here, you can define and accordingly place all your variables (user, password, host, port) independently as per your need.

Since your answer is concerned for request: This [discussion](https://github.com/request/request/issues/894) shall be of help.

Comment: how would I separate it into pieces like that?

Comment: By concatenating it all into one string as shown in the second example. In that, all the 4 terms are independent of each other, they need to be defined separately though.

Comment: Was this answer helpful to you? If it was kindly accept it so that it may serve a useful purpose for future users of Stack Overflow. Cheers.